# How to import a js file from src to public folder/service worker file

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, importerror

I have to set my firebase config to initialize it in my service worker, but i want to pass it with my config file, because I have more than one project and which one with it's respective firebase config. I was using this solution:

```
import project from '../src/config';
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.6.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp(project.firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

But now I'm receiving the following message:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Do someone know a workaround to this?

Comment: Hi Gilson, would you able to resolve this? I'm also facing the same problem where i need to import the config as variable depends on different environment

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I'll post what I've learned and done to workaround this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default firebase will try to get it own Service Worker, but [you can change it](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.messaging.Messaging#useServiceWorker) with useServiceWorker.
With this function you can select your own Service Worker.

So I setted a new Service Worker getting the name of the project like this:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register(`./firebase-messaging-sw-${project.name_project.toLowerCase()}.js`, {
      scope: '/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope'
    })
```

and after I just registered it

```
.then(function (registration) {
      if (registration) {
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration)
      }
```

I had to create in the public folder a service worker for each one of my projects, but worked.

Hope that will help you too